# Are VoIP Apps Restarted on Device Boot if the User Force Closed them Before Rebooting?

Tags: ios, voip, multitasking

I found this line in the iOS App Programming Guide:

> Including the voip value in the UIBackgroundModes key lets the system
>   know that it should allow the app to run in the background as needed
>   to manage its network sockets. **An app with this key is also relaunched
>   in the background immediately after system boot to ensure that the
>   VoIP services are always available.**

And I find this statement to be true in general.  However, if the user **force closed the application before rebooting their device**, my experience has been that the app is not automatically relaunched on device boot.  Can I get some clarification on the expected behavior in this particular case?

Comment: Your observation is correct. I think the general rule is that if user force closes the app then he/she will have to manually relaunch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credit goes to "The Eskimo" on this one...

> It's generally true that apps that the user 'quits' using the
>   multitasking UI are not automatically launched again.  The system
>   takes that as a hint from the user that it should not relaunch the
>   app.  If the user wants the app to be automatically launched in
>   future, they must manually launch it at least once.
>
> For VoIP apps this has been the case since VoIP support was introduced.  For other
>   types of automatically launched apps the implementation of this
>   heuristic has been less consistent, although I believe that with iOS 7
>   it's now applied across the board.